# Load views in Select and view selected value in a textbox

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to load 'roles' into a select control.
The select gets populated correctly with this:

```
 var user = new spatest.myrole(result.roleid, result.rolename);
```

but not with this:

```
var user = new spatest.roleViewModel(result.roleid, result.rolename);
```

Ultimately, I want to populate the values of each role in the select control and then when selecting each role, I want the rolename and roleid to appear on the textboxes:

```
<input id="idrolename" type="text" data-bind="value: rolename" />
<input id="idroleid" type="text" data-bind="value: roleid"  />
```

I'm a beginner in Knockout!

My view.html:

```
<div class="dnnFormItem">
    <div><label for="itemUser">[Resx:{key:"lblAssignedUser"}]</label></div>
    <select id="rolesid" data-bind="options: roleList,
                                    optionsText: 'rolename',
                                    optionsValue: 'roleid',
                                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</div>
```

My JS file:

```
var spatest = spatest || {};

spatest.roleListViewModel = function (moduleId, resx) {

    var service = {
        path: "spatest",
        framework: $.ServicesFramework(moduleId)
    }
    service.baseUrl = service.framework.getServiceRoot(service.path);

    var isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    var roleList = ko.observableArray([]);


    var init = function () {
        getRoleList();
    }

    var getRoleList = function () {
        isLoading(true);

        // need to calculate a different Url for User service
        var restUrl = service.framework.getServiceRoot(service.path) + "Myroles/Roles/";
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: restUrl,
            beforeSend: service.framework.setModuleHeaders,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).done(function (data) {            
            if (data) {
                load(data);
            }
            else {
                clear();
            }
        }).always(function (data) {
            isLoading(false);
        });
    };

    var load = function (data) {      
        roleList.removeAll();
        var underlyingArray = roleList();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var result = data[i];
            var user = new spatest.roleViewModel(result.roleid, result.rolename);
           //  var user = new spatest.myrole(result.roleid, result.rolename);
           // var user = { roleid: result.roleid, rolename: result.rolename };
            underlyingArray.push(user);
        }
        roleList.valueHasMutated();
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        load: load,
        roleList: roleList,
        isLoading: isLoading
    }
};

spatest.roleViewModel = function () {

    var roleid = ko.observable('');
    var rolename = ko.observable('');

    var load = function (data) {
        roleid(data.roleid)
        rolename(data.rolename);
    };


    return {
        roleid: roleid,
        rolename: rolename,
        load: load
    }
}


spatest.myrole = function (roleid, rolename) {
    this.roleid = roleid;
    this.rolename = rolename;
}

spatest.roleChanged = function (obj, event) {

    if (event.originalEvent) { //user changed
        alert('1');
    } else { // program changed
        alert('2');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `roleViewModel` is set up with an internal `load` function that does the assignment, so after

```
var user = new spatest.roleViewModel(result.roleid, result.rolename);
```

you need to do

```
user.load(result);
```

Comment: If I do that then I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleid' of undefined' here:  roleid(data.roleid)

Comment: Right, you have to pass in `data`. Make it `user.load(result)`. But you should probably just use the values passed to the rolemodel (which are currently ignored).

Comment: ok, with this the select control loads the values correctly. The last thing is when an option is selected, how do I display rolename and roleid on the textboxes? Thanks for your time

Comment: I can't tell which viewmodel the inputs are bound to. Your `<select>` uses only `roleid` for its value, so you're going to lose `rolename`. Unset `optionsValue`, add a `value` binding so something gets set when it is selected, then refer to that something in the `value` bindings of your inputs.

Comment: the model should be 'roleViewModel'. I believe each item in the select is a model now? Sorry, it's the first time I interact with knockout

Comment: Have you been through [the Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)? It is great for getting up to speed.

Comment: thanks for the link. I'm just pulling my hair because my setup appears tricky. I have tried to subscribe to the changes of the select but everything gives an error. Thanks anyway